# Kindle Fire: Minimizing the slim gray bar at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, kindle, kindle-fire

At the bottom of an app running on Kindle Fire, there's a slim gray bar with the Home button, Back button, Menu button, and Search button.

I've seen some apps minimize this gray bar automatically after X seconds of no use (in such a way that it's even slimmer, and there's only one button visible: the maximize button). How is this accomplished? For my app, the gray bar stays maximized throughout the entire duration of the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is this accomplished?

The bar will minimize for activities that request to have the full screen (e.g., `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` on the `<activity>` element in the manifest).

Comment: @r1k0: If by "3.0" you mean Android 3.0+, then no. If a device has a system bar, the system bar is a permanent fixture.

Comment: how about hiding the search icon or other elements? www.stackoverflow.com/questions/10956808/kindle-fire-menu-actionbar-search-icon-shows-on-every-activity-need-to-supres

Answer (score 0):

The bar is minimized like you want when the activity is in full-screen mode.
In your activity's onCreate method you can request full-screen mode as follows:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Do this right after calling super.onCreate()